# Highest level curve per (Voronoi) polygon?

Tags: qgis, elevation

I am facing a difficulty in QGIS (2.8.2):
I have three layers:

- layer 1: layer with points
- layer 2: layer of level curves (contour lines)
- layer 3: layer of Voronoi polygons obtained from the points layer (layer 1).

What I need to get is, for each point (layer 1), the highest elevation contained in its respective Voronoi polygon.

How could it be done?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use a raster elevation dataset. If you can't get hold of the one used to create the contours (presuming they weren't done by hand from point data) you can:

- Open menu Raster/Conversion/Rasterize (Vector to Raster)
- Choose your contour (level curves) file and a suitable grid size (likely based on the area you wish to work with and contour resolution)
- Press OK.

You can then sample the resulting raster for the Voronoi polygons:

- Make sure you have the 'Zonal Statistics' plugin activated
- Select your voronoi polygon layer for zones
- State the column prefix you want for the new columns
- Choose what you want reporting
- Press OK.

From here you need to join the point and voronoi layer, either by attribute or location.